# Gtk-based Mono.WebBrowser on Windows

Tags: c#, mono, webkit, gtk

I'm trying to come up with the simplest example of using the
Mono.WebBrowser using Gtk on Windows. The Windows.Forms version works
fine (the default if you don't specify Platform.Gtk), but I need to integrate into an existing Gtk cross-platform application.

Here is a simple example:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Gtk.Application.Init ();
    Gtk.Window win = new Gtk.Window ("Title");
    Mono.WebBrowser.IWebBrowser browser =
        Mono.WebBrowser.Manager.GetNewInstance(Mono.WebBrowser.Platform.Gtk);
    browser.Load(win.Handle, 500, 250);
    win.ShowAll ();
    GLib.Timeout.Add( 500, delegate {
        browser.Navigation.Go ("http://google.com/");
        return false;
    });
    Gtk.Application.Run ();
}
```

which compiles, runs, and browser.Initialized is true. But it doesn't render into a Gtk.Window (or any other Gtk.widget I have tried). What triggers
the browser to actually render itself? It may be that I can't render this
directly into a Window (I've looked at the mono-docbrowser [1] source,
and have a more complicated example, but it doesn't render either).

I have looked at webkit-sharp, but can't get it to work on Windows or Mac with Gtk.

[1] https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/tree/master/docbrowser

Comment: Hi, Doug! I have an exactly your problem - I need a cross-platform Mono GTK# web browser([for user interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518973/gtk-html-viewer-for-ui)). So what you finally chose? Regards!

Comment: I gave up. If things haven't changed in the last 5 years, perhaps having different solutions on different platforms could be an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't recall exactly where, but I read somewhere that the Mono.WebBrowser namespace was somehow deprecated in favor of WebkitSharp.

I tried something like that before, but I used webkit-sharp.dll from my linux distribution. Tried to compile it and run it on windows but it did not worked. So it turned out that I was missing the webkit-gtk dll which is the one that actually renders the whole thing (webkit-sharp is just glue-code, a wrapper if you will)

I sent an email back then to one of the maintainers (Andreia Gaita) and got a response that might help you (about using webkit-sharp in windows/osx) drop me a line and I'll forward you that mail.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising!

Comment: I have tried contacting you via email; please forward the email. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I will need to contact the original authors and see what I can piece together. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said in the mail, I'm not quite sure how but the thing should work, I actually tried past weekend with updated versions of webkitgtk and gtk sharp still threw the excepcion about not finding "webkit-1.0" so for me sounds like a name mapping issue (internally the webkitgtk library might be named something else)

Comment: @GustavoRubio hi! And what she exactly said? Can I use webkit-sharp in windows and os x? And how? Regards!

Comment: @GustavoRubio sorry, I asking you due to the I don't get any response from her, so any your help will be very useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Gluezilla](https://github.com/mono/gluezilla) is dead (doesn't work with new Firefox) and [Webkit-sharp](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp) is not mature yet (technically not dead, but I've heard the result is mostly the same). I don't know of other options.

Comment: Ok, that confirms what I have seen, at least as much as a cross-platform solution. webkit-sharp works great, on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm what Gustavo said: Mono.WebBrowser has never worked for me. The issue with webkit-sharp is that even if it's cross-platform, it hates Windows. webkit-sharp is in fact a .NET binding for webkit-gtk (e.g. embedding WebKit in a Gtk window). But even if both Gtk#/Mono, and WebKit all work on Windows, webkit-gtk makes a lot of trouble here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why your code don't work, but I can suggest you on using Awesomium, a hacked source of Chromium that you can integrate either in a C++ or a .Net application.

Their wiki is pretty incomplete but the SDK download contains several examples on how to use it.

Awesomium: http://awesomium.com/
Wiki: http://wiki.awesomium.net/

Comment: It appears that this is only winforms and WPF. I need Gtk.

Comment: It runs even over OpenGL, you just need to wrap the events and copy the pixel buffers to your Gtk window.

Comment: "Just" wrapping the events and copying the pixel buffers does not seem trivial. But, in fact, it seems like that is what the Mono Docbrowser does. But I cannot get it to work; it does not display.