# GTK# HTML viewer for UI

Tags: user-interface, mono, webkit, gtk, gtk#

I want to create a cross-platform GTK# application with HTML/CSS/JS user interface. I already found [Gtk.HTML rendering widget](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3AGtk.HTML), but it does not support CSS and JS(I think that because thus it is written on this page).
So what are the options I have to accomplish this task?

Comment: Is there a WebKitGTK+ binding for C#?

Comment: @andlabs yes, and I already found it. But is it possible to call C# from JavaScript(e.g. for interception onclick events), call JavaScript from C#(not necessary but will be nice) and change some elements on the already loaded page?

Comment: I don't know; you would have to check the documentation and any examples that come with the source. Good luck!

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: @Behrooz sorry, I missed your question. Unfortunately no, I thought this isn't the most elegant solution.

Comment: @don-prog Well, I did, Used GtkWebkitSharp and it works almost flawlessly on windows, Linux and mac. Send me a message If you still need it.

Comment: @Behrooz glad you did it! I don't need it anymore, but I guess that other people will be pleased if you share your solution in this post :)